# Create a Mosiac image gallary inside a set Div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a pinterest style board for mobile my web application which is going to be just html, css and javascript/jquery (at the moment i'm just coding them as static pages) No frameworks such as bootstrap. It needs to work on different screen dimensions therefore need to be responsive, to achieve this I tried to use flexbox however this didnt work either

[image]

I have made an initial attempt however i'm relatively new to web development and cannot get the images stay within the "board-inner" div. As the images will be different sizes, I need them to fit

```css
/* CSS for Login-image-holder  */

.main-column-holder {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fit, minmax(350px, 1fr));
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.column-holder {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}


/* CSS for collection-holder  */

.board-holder {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  border: #b2b2b2 1px solid;
  height: 310px;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.board {
  height: 100%;
}

.board-inner {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-items: center;
}

.board-image {
  width: 32%;
  height: auto;
}

.detailer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: white;
}

.board-inline {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.counter {
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.board-author {
  align-self: flex-end;
}


}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="main-column-holder">
    <div class="column-holder">

      <div class="board-holder">
        <!--   Board -->
        <div class="board">
          <div class="board-inner">
            <img class="board-image" src="https://source.unsplash.com/HtHrjExpddA" alt="">
            <img class="board-image" src="https://source.unsplash.com/Y--zr3CPaPs" alt="">
            <img class="board-image" src="https://source.unsplash.com/W7QkaUbYEmg" alt="">
            <img class="board-image" src="https://source.unsplash.com/4dhlFpZ0dDw" alt="">
            <img class="board-image" src="https://source.unsplash.com/QMRN_GX7p4I" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- detail Holder-->
        <div class="detailer">
          <div class="board-header">
            <h3 class="header">Animals</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="board-inline">
            <div class="counter">
              <p class="count_text"><span class="counter">73</span> Photos</p>
            </div>
            <div class="board-author">
              <p class="author_text"><span class="author">Jon Bucket</span></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

inside the board-inner div and resize if required.

```
https://codepen.io/humzaysf/pen/WNvrjGJ
```

Comment: Please provide what you have tried so far in `css`

Comment: @johannchopin html and css added

Comment: your images are too big. When I resized them to:
**`.board-image {
    width: 13%;
    height: auto;
  }`**

the grid displayed correctly.
also, consider using a grid for the inner board instead of flexbox.
It might be easier for you to manage.